# "what this all is about" or "what this is all about"

Tags: phrase-request, adverbs, word-order

One wrote:

> You might guess what **this all is about** from the headline if you are up to date

I changed it into:

> You might have already guessed what **this is all about** from the post's title if you are up to date with news.

First, I like to know is it "what this is all about" or "what this all is about"? Can one say "what these are all about" when speaking of a post in a forum?

Second, which is idiomatic

- if you are up to date
- if you are up to date with news
- if you are up with news
- if you keep up on/with news

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to *multiple items*

> A flurry of tweets today and **what this all is about** is the Trump cabinet. *(present)*
>   A flurry of tweets yesterday and **what these all were about** was the Trump cabinet. *(past)*

If you are referring to a single item (a post)

> What the post **is all about** is the selection of his cabinet.

The patterns you are using are

> "All is about" talks about several things regarding one thing.
>
> Lots of activity tweeting and what this all is about is the cabinet selection.
>   *what the various tweets are about is the cabinet selection*

or

> "Is all about..." talks about a single thing talking about one thing in depth
>
> His tweet **is all about** the cabinet selection.
>   *his tweet describes the cabinet selection in detail and nothing else*

To stay current with the news

> if you are up to date
>   if you are up to date with **the** news
>   if you are up with **the** news
>   if you are up **on** the news
>   if you keep up **with** the news